# Android : How to make sure that sharedPreference get clear before running a large nos of test in Instrumentation testing

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I have an app which contain a login page. In this login page i am storing user credentials in shared preference if user already login it will directly goes to splash screen then dashboard. But in case of android Instrumentation testing. My test case runs for only once since for the first time user credential is not stored in shared preference. once credentials has been stored in shared preference it will automatically redirect the test case to splash screen on start of the test.  hence my test case is failed.

I want to clear my app sharedpreference everytime before i run login test case.

I tried to clear my sharedpreference from taking context using getInstrumentation().getContext(). but it seem its not working.

I have to write multiple test cases where i will have to run atleast 15 test cases in this same class. So for every @test i need to clear the shared preference first all the time.

below is code for my login test case:

```
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import salesken.app.R;

import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

public class LoginActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule < LoginActivity > loginActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule < LoginActivity > (LoginActivity.class);

    private LoginActivity loginActivity = null;

    private String email_input = "dummy@user.com";
    private String password_input = "password1";
    private int timeout = 5000;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(SplashScreenActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        loginActivity = loginActivityTestRule.getActivity();
        clearsharedPref();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        loginActivity = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void autenticationcheck() {
        clearsharedPref();

        EditText email = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.email);
        EditText password = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.password);
        Button login = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.login);
        email.setText(email_input);
        password.setText(password_input);
        onView(withId(R.id.login)).perform(ViewActions.click());
        SplashScreenActivity splashScreenActivity = (SplashScreenActivity) getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, timeout);
        assertNotNull(splashScreenActivity);
        splashScreenActivity.finish();
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyEmail() {
        clearsharedPref();
        EditText email = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.email);
        EditText password = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.password);
        Button login = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.login);
        email.setText("");
        password.setText(password_input);
        onView(withId(R.id.login)).perform(ViewActions.click());
        SplashScreenActivity splashScreenActivity = (SplashScreenActivity) getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, timeout);
        assertNull(splashScreenActivity);
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyPassword() {
        clearsharedPref();
        EditText email = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.email);
        EditText password = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.password);
        Button login = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.login);
        email.setText("");
        password.setText(password_input);
        onView(withId(R.id.login)).perform(ViewActions.click());
        SplashScreenActivity splashScreenActivity = (SplashScreenActivity) getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, timeout);
        assertNull(splashScreenActivity);
    }

    public void clearsharedPref() {
        Context context = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SaleskenProComplexKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clear all by

```
Context context = getInstrumentation().getContext();
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("mysharedpref", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.clear(); 
editor.commit();
```

Comment: this code will never work on android unit test case

Comment: check updated code in question the problem is i have three test cases autenticationcheck, emptyEmail, emptyPassword. the code you mention works for autenticationcheck and emptyEmail. but when it run empty password it wont be able to clear the shared preference. I am running my test case on emulator pixel api 28

Comment: it work for couple of time. but i think there is some issue in clearing shared preference again and again between Test when you scale your test cases like 15-20

Comment: SharedPreferences won't work every time perfectly on certain devices, especially, Xiaomi devices. You need to restart the devices for it to happen. Emulators also have some kind of bugs @FerozSiddiqui

Comment: I am write a regression suite. It's kind of troubling me alot where it can create a mess for my regression suite. Should I put some sleep before executing the next test case?

Answer (score 1):

Clearing `SharedPrferences` should be enough, if not, you can delete it instead of clearing:

```
String filePath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getParent()+"/shared_prefs/prefs_name.xml";
    File deletePrefFile = new File(filePath);
     deletePrefFile.delete();
```

If I can't get Context of an application with easy way I use:

```
public class ApplicationContext extends Application {

    private static ApplicationContext INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        INSTANCE = this;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```